# Way to inject custom props/methods to `handleSubmit`?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-context, react-hook-form, unstated

I'm using [react hook form](https://react-hook-form.com/), and I'm looking for a way to inject custom props to the `handleSubmit` method returned by the hook. The reason I need to do this is my component acts as a `Consumer` for a [state library](https://github.com/jamiebuilds/unstated), and I want to update the state after submitting the form. I may also want to pass props to the method.

From looking at the API, it seems like this isn't possible. Any thoughts on a workaround or how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't use this library, but it seems that `getValues` function returned from `useForm` hook opens the way to synchronize Your component state with form data stored in the "react-hook-form":

[docs](https://react-hook-form.com/api#getValues)

```
import React, { useMemo, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";

export default function App() {
  const { register, getValues } = useForm();
  const [ valuesState, setValuesState ] = useState();

  const values = useMemo(() => getValues());

  useEffect(() => setValuesState(values), [values]);

  return (
    <form>
      [...]
    </form>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

why not just update the state during `handleSubmit`?

```
export default function App() {
  const { register, getValues } = useForm();
  const onSubmit = data => {
    // do your state update here update(data)
  }

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
      [...]
    </form>
  );
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, in my situation, I had no access to state from the body of the function, only from the `return (...)` block. I was using https://github.com/jamiebuilds/unstated.

But @Mateusz proposed a good solution imo.